# Datatables: You clicked on undefined's row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I have this definition of a Datatable defined on a Thymeleaf template of a SpringBoot application, using Datatables:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#workerEventTable').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/acerinox/api/deviceevent/datatableList',      
           "columns": [
               { data: 'id' },
               { data: 'deviceId' },
               { data: 'companyName' },
               { data: 'description' },
               { data: 'battery' },
               { data: 'dateTime' },
               { data: 'signal' },           
               { data: 'data' },
               { data: 'alarm' }
           ] 
    });

    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
    }, 1000 );


    table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
          localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
    })

    $('#workerEventTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );

} );

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Expecting that when I click on a row I should see the ID, but instead I see this error message: `Datatables: You clicked on undefined's row`

Comment: You are using object based data because you defined `columns.data`.  To access the `id` try this: `alert( 'You clicked on '+data.id+'\'s row' );`.

Comment: @KThorngren, it works ! Please convert to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using object based data because you defined columns.data. To access the id try this:

```
alert( 'You clicked on '+data.id+'\'s row' );
```